# Make right+left click emulate middle click on wireless mouse

Tags: wireless, mouse, scripts, logitech

Anybody have or know of a sweet little workaround script I can set to running at startup that would allow my dilapidated mouse to keep providing me with middleclick functionality even though the normal button's busted?

In other words, on the *mouse*, if I press the left and right buttons simultaneously or within a few ms of each other, it'd pipe a middle click through.